# App.config problems (Schemas)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, app-config

I've got this problem with my app.config file in my console application.

Here's my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="PROJECTNAME.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <userSettings>
    <PROJECTNAME.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="SETTING1" serializeAs="String">
        <value>stringvariable</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="SETTING2" serializeAs="String">
        <value>boolvariable</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="SETTING3" serializeAs="String">
        <value>intvariable</value>
      </setting>
    </PROJECTNAME.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

If I only have the default schema (DotNetConfig.xsd) I get the following warnings:

```
Message 1   Could not find schema information for the element 'userSettings'.   PROJECTPATH\App.config
Message 2   Could not find schema information for the element 'PROJECTNAME.Properties.Settings'.    PROJECTPATH\App.config
Message 3   Could not find schema information for the element 'setting'.    PROJECTPATH\App.config
Message 4   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'name'. PROJECTPATH\App.config
Message 5   Could not find schema information for the attribute 'serializeAs'.  PROJECTPATH\App.config
Message 6   Could not find schema information for the element 'value'.  PROJECTPATH\App.config
```

Message 3-6 repeats itself 3 times.

If I then go to XML > Create schema, it creates a app.xsd but then it gives me another warning:

```
 Warning    1   The global element 'configuration' has already been declared.   App.xsd
```

I've been trying to fix this problem for a few days now, with no result. And I can't find a solution using Google